# Regular measures: equivalent properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb R^n, \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n))$.

Why are the three following properties absolutely equivalent?

1. $\mu(A) = $ inf {$\mu(U): A \subset U, U \text{ open} $} for all $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$
2. $\mu(A) = $ sup {$\mu(K): K \subset A, K \text{ compact} $} for all $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$
3. $\mu(A) = $ sup {$\mu(C): C \subset A, C \text{ closed} $} for all $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: 1 and 2 are not equivalent, they are just properties of regular measures

Comment: For a finite measure the three properties are equivalent. In general equivalence of 2) and 3) follows from the fact that any closed is a countable union of compact sets.

Comment: I don't think that 1) and 2) are equivalent if the measure is not finite. For finite measures, all of the properties are always true, and thus trivially equivalent.